# How to read string data from JAXBElement<byte[]>

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jaxb

I have a web-service which returns data in the below xml form

```
<EpsBinaryEx xmlns="http://Eprise">
<ErrorString>No Error</ErrorString>
<ErrorNum>1</ErrorNum>
<Data>ajhsdjasjajadjhgasd</Data>
</EpsBinaryEx>
```

Class EpsBinaryEx has a getData() method as below

```
public JAXBElement<byte[]> getData() {
        return data;
    }
```

My aim is to read the Data tag's content which is a Base64 String. Am calling the webservice and trying to read the element in the following way

```
PSWebService service = new PSWebService();                   
PSWebServiceSoap soap = service.getPSWebServiceSoap();
EpsBinaryEx base64Data = soap.getUploadedDocument(token, pageId);
System.out.println(base64Data.getData.getValue());
```

This gives the offset address as output. I tried using `Arrays.toString(base64Data.getData().getValue())` and `(new String(base64Data.getData().getValue())` as well. But the first method gives me an array of numbers and second method displays non-readable characters.

Can you please help me out in reading the Data tag? I need my output to be "ajhsdjasjajadjhgasd" in the above example.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Sam.

Comment: Are you saying you want to get the original Base64 characters?

Comment: well something like that. My actual goal is to decode that Base64 string and create a pdf file. But am unable to send the Base64 string to my decode method. I hope am clear in my answer.

Comment: If the XML schema (which either is referred to by the WSDL, or is embedded directly in the WSDL) defines the Data element as type [base64Binary](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#base64Binary), then that byte array *is* your PDF document;  it's already been Base64 decoded.

Comment: Thanks VGR. I know that the byte array is the PDF. I just dont know how to read this byte array and create PDF out of it. Can you please advise? I tried converting byte array to string. But as I have mentioned in my question, I get non-readable characters.

Comment: Pass a [ByteArrayInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html) to whatever PDF library you prefer to use.  I'm not an expert on working with PDFs in Java, but two such libraries that I know of are [iText](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itext/) and [PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/).

Comment: Actually, you may not even need a PDF library, if all you intend to do is write the bytes to a file;  just use [Files.write](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write-java.nio.file.Path-byte:A-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-) or [OutputStream.write](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#write-byte:A-).

Comment: Am sorry VGR. Maybe I was not clear in my answer. The main problem is,  am unable to read the JAXBElement<byte[]>. Typically we give Arrays.toString() to read a byte array. But this being a JAX bean, am not sure how to read it. Once I figure out a way to read/output this data in string form, I can create the PDF with no issues.

Comment: The Arrays.toString methods are for logging and debugging.  I do not understand why you feel you need a String.  Perhaps you should edit your question to show the code you would use to create a PDF if you had a String.

Comment: Thanks for the help @VGR. As you said, the string was already decoded. I just had to use FileOutputStream to write a pdf file. Thank you so much :)

Comment: @Sam, I think you should post an example (answer) of how you were able to read the byte array from the JAXBElement, that way anyone finding this question will have an answer!  Just my 2 cents!